# Передача массива из функции в функцию

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пытаюсь передать массив в функцию sum, но она его не видит, почему?

```js
function range(start, end) {
    let matrix = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        matrix.push(i);
    }
    return matrix;
}

function sum(matrix) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.lenght; i++) {
        sum += matrix[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(sum(range(1, 5)));
```

Comment: Ошибка в слове length -> `matrix.lenght` должно быть -> `matrix.length`

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил опечатку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас опечатка в слове `length` в функции `sum`.

```js
function range(start, end) {
    let matrix = [];
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        matrix.push(i);
    }
    return matrix;
}

function sum(matrix) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        sum += matrix[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

console.log(sum(range(1, 5)));
```